# How to remove black dots from the edge of the patch?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am using the contour filter to remove the black dots on the edge of the patch, but the problem persists. Is there any way to remove those dots?

The result of the extraction of the green stain:
[image]

And this is the image already superimposed on the background image and you can see the black dots on the edge:
[image]

This is the code to extract the green stain:

```
image = cv2.imread('/content/frame_patch.jpg')

img_hsv=cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#color boundaries [H, S, V]
lower = (44, 30, 10)
upper = (120, 255, 255)

# threshold on green color
thresh = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower, upper)

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw
mask = np.zeros_like(image)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [big_contour], 0, (255,255,255), -1)

img_result = image.copy()
img_result[mask==0] = 0
```

The background image:
[image]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71843794/how-to-insert-in-a-specific-position-of-the-background-image-the-foreground-obje/71846647#71846647) is the merge code.

Comment: OpenCV images are BGR not RGB. So change cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV to cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV. View your thresh image to be sure it is acceptable and not over or under thresholded. Consider thresholding on black using cv2.inRange() on the BGR image, then invert to get your mask.  But what difference is it going to be if you have dark dots or you draw your contour of the green on a black background. Your dots will then be perfectly black.  Consider drawing on a green background color.

Comment: Is your image normal full resolution or have you zoomed it? If the latter, post the original full resolution image without any zoom.

Comment: The image I posted is already the image overlaid on top of a background image.
Yes, the original image has a black background that you can't make out those dots, but you do notice when inserting as a foreground object into the background images.

Comment: Your images are not the same scale. Why? What code is used to merge the images?  Please explain further each image and how it was created. Which image is frame_patch.jpg? If neither, please post that so we can run your code.

Comment: frame_patch.jpg is the green stain. As for the size of the green spot, after its extraction it is reduced for insertion in the background image. I updated the post.

Comment: Post your background image without the stain and show your code for merging them

Comment: I updated the post. The code for merging is in the link at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that you might try is to use morphology in Python/OpenCV to close and erode your thresh image.

Note that I draw it on a gray background to see how the black border is reduced. You can go back to your black background for proper subsequent processing, if needed.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('stain.png')

img_hsv=cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#color boundaries [H, S, V]
lower = (44, 30, 10)
upper = (120, 255, 255)

# threshold on green color
thresh = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower, upper)

# use morphology to (optionally close and then) erode the thresh image
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw
mask = np.zeros_like(image)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [big_contour], 0, (255,255,255), -1)

img_result = image.copy()
img_result[mask==0] = 128

# write results to disk
cv2.imwrite("stain_mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("stain_result.png", img_result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result", img_result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thresh with Morphology:

[image]

Result on gray:

[image]