# How to insert a foreground object to the background image's perspective?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

In the previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71843794/how-to-insert-in-a-specific-position-of-the-background-image-the-foreground-obje) I asked how to insert a foreground object into a background image, but this time it goes further, how I could insert that foreground object into the perspective of the background image (from the vehicle view)?. That is, the final composite image should look as realistic as possible.

The background image (taken from the vehicle):
[image]

The stain (foreground object) taken from above:
[image]

The code is in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71843794/how-to-insert-in-a-specific-position-of-the-background-image-the-foreground-obje).

The result achieved so far:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a camera model for your scene? If not, then you need to estimate the tilt and focal length or field of view. Then for the tilt and focal length do a perspective transform to warp your face-on view of the stain into the geometry of the background scene.

Comment: No, the images are collected from different sources, so they have a perspective problem.

Comment: I understand. But to warp the face-on view of the stain to the perspective of the background, you need a camera model for the background or you need to estimate the tilt some how. Search Google to see if you can find a way to estimate the tilt from the y position of the horizon, though that may now really work well, here. If you were to take the image from ground level at Z=0, the horizon would be at the bottom. As you tilt the camera down, the horizon raises higher in the image. So you could compute the tilt angle (as a crude estimate). Then tilt the perspective of the stain image.

Comment: You can explore alpha blending