# How to fix The operation is neither 'array op array' when adding watermark to image

Tags: python, image, opencv, watermark

I'm new to OpenCV and Python. I'm trying to add watermark to an image and have been following this Youtube tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zbJ3EY4s9r8

**This is the error that I get:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\Desktop\watermark\watermark3.py", line 27, in 
> result = cv2.addWeighted(roi,1,logo,0.3,0) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5)
> D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:650:
> error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is
> neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same
> number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in
> function 'cv::arithm_op'

I think I have followed the same instruction from the video:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

logo = cv2.imread("images/testlogo2.png")
h_logo, w_logo, _=logo.shape
print(h_logo, w_logo)

images_path = glob.glob("C:/Users/User/Desktop/testimage/*.*")
#deciding the position of the logo
for img_path in images_path:
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    h_img, w_img, _=img.shape
    print(h_img, w_img)
    center_x = int(w_img/2)
    center_y = int(h_img/2)
    top_y=center_y+int(h_logo/2)
    left_x=center_x+int(w_logo/2)
    bottom_y=h_logo+top_y
    right_x=w_logo+left_x

    #roi
    roi = img[top_y:bottom_y, left_x:right_x]

    # Add the Logo to the Roi
    result = cv2.addWeighted(roi,1,logo,0.3,0)

    # Replace the ROI on the image
    img[top_y: bottom_y, left_x: right_x] = result

    # Get filename and save the image
    filename = os.path.basename(img_path)
    cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/User/Desktop/testimage/new/logo_"+filename,img)

print("Watermark added to al the images")
```

Comment: Make sure `roi` and `logo` are of same dimensions. Please read https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html

Comment: Does this help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71843794/how-to-insert-in-a-specific-position-of-the-background-image-the-foreground-obje/71846647#7184664](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71843794/how-to-insert-in-a-specific-position-of-the-background-image-the-foreground-obje/71846647#71846647)