# Python making Hologram pyramid

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am studying on hologram vision. I want  to placed 4 images onto black screen.

[image]

I wrote this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from screeninfo import get_monitors

if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen = get_monitors()[0]
    print(screen)
    width, height = screen.width, screen.height

    image = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.float64)
    image[:, :] = 0  # black screen
    img = cv2.imread("newBen.png")
    p = 0.25
    w = int(img.shape[1])
    h = int(img.shape[0])
    new_img = cv2.resize(img, (w, h))
    image[:h, :w] = new_img
    window_name = 'projector'
    cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
    cv2.moveWindow(window_name, screen.x - 1, screen.y - 1)
    cv2.setWindowProperty(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,
    cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
    cv2.imshow(window_name, image)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But my image looking like this.

[image]

How can ı fix it?

Comment: Does this help? [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71843794/how-to-insert-in-a-specific-position-of-the-background-image-the-foreground-obje/71846647#71846647

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dtype` of a normal RGB image is `uint8`, not `float64`.

```
image = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Btw: You don't have to set `image[:, :] = 0  # black screen`. This is already been done by `np.zeros`.

Comment: thank you. when applied this, the problem resolved.